Regular expression - same group later
(This is in java) I am trying to match this string
"aaaBaaa"

using this java regex
(a+)B\1

The \1 is supposed to mean first group (the a+ portion of the pattern)
But this is wrong and doesn't work. I know that regexes have something like that, but i can't remember how to invoke it.

EDIT:
This is the task :
Returns true if for every '*' (star) in the string, if there are chars both immediately before and after the star, they are the same.


sameStarChar("xy*yzz") → true
sameStarChar("xy*zzz") → false
sameStarChar("*xa*az") → true

And this is how i am trying to solve it:
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[*]|(.)([*])\1");
  java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  return matcher.find();
}


Works for me:  https://rubular.com/r/v3vx1ABIyGdSXS What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How are you using the regex? Please show your code.

Support for certain regex features  depends on the implementation. What is the language you are using regex with?

Why would *xa*az return true that the first * has nothing preceded?

\1 is an invalid escape sequence in a string. You must escape the backslash itself, so that it can be seen by the regex parser: "[*]|(.)([*])\\1".

@Hoa, note that the challenge says "if there are chars both immediately before and after the star". This means that there is no equality constraint if this is not true.

And this is one of the reasons the [tag:regex] tag tells you to specify the language.

The task sounds like ([^*])\*\1 (as Java String double the backslashes)

The problem is that in your sameStarChar regex, the first alternative [*] will match as soon as there is an asterisk in your input string. Even if the second alternative pattern fails, it will not matter.
Secondly, the backslash needs to be escaped or otherwise the regex parser will never see it.
I would suggest matching the opposite, i.e. strings that fail the requirement, and then return the boolean opposite of that.
An input fails if there is an asterisk with a preceding character and successive character that are different. So:
    public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\*(?!\\1).");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        return !matcher.find();
    }

This way the function will also return true when the input does not have an asterisk at all, or only one at the very start or very end of the input.
